# Similar web UI experience as we see on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, javascript

I like Windows Phone 7's interface experience. I find it very innovative compared to other interfaces (be it mobile, desktop or web). Yet it's still no less usable. All in all a very good shift from the usual in the right direction.

Some of the effects could be used in web interfaces to enhance the experience without sacrificing usability and intuitiveness.

Effects I'm talking about:

- perspective animation when you click on a particular hub on the home screen)
- elements executing animation in different times (hub being clicked moves last)
- horizontal slide with different slide amounts (titles and background images move less than screen width which gives it a feeling of depth dimension)
- etc.

### 2 questions

1. Do you know of any public website that uses at least one of the aforementioned effects and does that without the use of plugins (like Flash or Silverlight)?
2. Is there any JavaScript library that would provide such effects (at least the different delay and different amount sliding technique)?

### Extremely simplified example

I've taken some time to [put up a simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/uW7VR/) of transition effect that could be adopted on mobile devices and *simulates* at least a bit of the fine Windows Phone 7.x transitions.

Just click on any tile and see others zoom out and slide to left.

Let me know what you think about this example.

### Something came out just these days

Take a look at [this HTML demo](http://m.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/demo/index.html) written by Microsoft (or one of its partners). Blew my mind away as being the closest to WP7 experience! **Amazing**!

Comment: +1, I have also been looking for something like this. What I am not sure is on a bigger screen, would windows phone metro UI still look good? Until I saw this video. http://www.microsoft.com/office/vision/ I think you don't really need to mimic what's currently in wp7, you can potentially do something better! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay and sliding should be easily handled by jQuery, but I am not aware of someone who has alredy bundled up something to directly emulate the WP7 interface. Sounds like a fun project.

Comment: Would be nice, wouldn't it? Even sliding could be combined into a nice library, that would be able to delay slide child elements of a particular container when we'd call something like `$("#container").variedSlideOut("left")`.

Comment: Seems the metro ui in windows 8 might be pretty close to this too ;p lots of JS in there apparently